# Python Battleship random number generator

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to classes in Python. While coding a battleship game I ran into a problem with choosing random x,y coordinates for the locations of computer's ships and the computer's attack coordinates. I am confused about whether to generate random numbers as a local variable in one of the functions or as Class attribute or instance attribute.

Initially I thought to create an instance attribute (below), but i got rand_x is not defined. I tried creating a Battleship function that generated random numbers, but it returned the same pair of coordinates every time it was called. Is the only way to do this to create a local variable for random #s? Because I will be using the random generator more than once it would be nice not to have to repeat that code.

Thanks for your patience.

EDIT: I've included more code with the randomness function, and replaced `size` in randomness function with `self.size`.

For example, Battleship(4,2,0,0) might give me a `hitlist` of [[2,1],[2,1]] I would like random #s inside `hitlist`.

```
import random
hitlist=[]; #a global variable

class Battleship(object):
    """ Ship object container. A game where the user tries to destroy the enemy's ships User tries to guess computer's position x and y """
    def __init__(self, size, numberships,position_x,position_y):
        self.position_x=position_x
        self.position_y=position_y
        self.numberships=numberships
        self.size = size

    def plotships(self,r):
        """input is integer coordinates for ships and output is an array of arrays with battleship locations CREATES THE HITLIST DONT REPEAT"""
        print('plotships function running')
        for i in range(self.numberships):
            hitlist.append(r) #random number from function randomness
            print(hitlist)
        return hitlist

   def randomness(self):
        rand_x=random.choice(range(self.size))
        rand_y=random.choice(range(self.size))
        randcoord=[rand_x,rand_y]
        return randcoord

#Game Interface
size=int(input('Gameboard size'))
numberships=int(input('Waiting for Number of enemy ships'))
b=Battleship(size,numberships,0,0)
random=b.randomness() #create a random x y coordinate
b.plotships(random) #create a hitlist
```

Comment: Make sure you imported `random`.
Try using `random.randint(0, self.size - (wtv is your x range)` and `random.randint(0, self.size - (wtv is your y range)`

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. As it stands the only way we can tell what's wrong is by guessing, which is almost certainly going to be wrong.

Comment: @ Imtiaz Raqib  This is %100 overthinking this problem, but you could use a more secure random number generator call (IE: `os.urandom`). Just don't want to see the enemy predict the location of your fleet Admiral @st4rgut.

Comment: Can you put in your question what sort of output you expect / want from b.plotships(random)? The it's written now, you're generating a list R of size two with two random numbers in the range 0-self.size; then you're creating (and printing on each increment) a list of size self.numberships; the elements of which are all going to be R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you're calling `random.choice` with `size` and not `self.size`.

i.e.

```
rand_x = random.choice(range(self.size))
```

Also, where are you defining `self.rand`? Surely you're getting problems in the constructor trying to print it?

EDIT - IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT BELOW:

If you want `hitlist` to be populated with `self.numberships` pairs of independent random number pairs, the write the `plotships` method as:

```
def plotships(self):
    """input is integer coordinates for ships and output is an
       array of arrays with battleship locations CREATES THE
       HITLIST DONT REPEAT"""
    print('plotships function running')
    for i in range(self.numberships):
        hitlist.append(randomness()) #random number from function randomness
        print(hitlist)
    return hitlist
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the leftover code self.rand. When I use self.size I think its still referring to the same instance and printing out the same random number pair.

Comment: indeed, seems to be main cause of the problem. thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your problem now. Should hitlist have different and independent pairs of random numbers?

Comment: yes, i should have said hitlist should return random number pairs

Answer (score 0):

To get a random number maybe you could import the random library.

You could use it to initialize your (X, Y) coordenates on an instance of your class.

```
import random

Battleship(size, numberships, random.randint(0, WIDTH), random.randint(0, HEIGHT))
```

I'm assuming you have the screen's widht and Height available. Hope it helps.